# The expression of photocurrent

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, photons, photoelectric-effect, photonics

Consider an electro-magnetic field represented in phasor notation $E_0e^{-jwt}$ incident upon a photodetector/photodiode, what is the expression of the generated photo-current $I(t)$? Here $E_0e^{-jwt}$ is an abstract way usually assumed for an optical signal in the Scattering-matrix method (or transfer-matrix method). $w$ corresponds to the angular frequency at wavelength $1550nm$.

I know the photo-current should be proportional to the incident power of the light. Also, I vaguely recall $|E_0|^2$ is proportional to the incident power of the EM field. But this value is a constant (time independent). If I remember correctly, this value $|E_0|^2$ corresponds to the average power in one period $T=2\pi/w$. Then, how do I express $I(t)$ in terms of $E_0$?

Comment: Do you know the size of T? does it matter for I? i(t) would be constant.

Comment: Photocurrent measured at the device terminals has many factors smoothing out any time response. Ultimately you need to go to the photon representation of the problem.

Comment: If $I(t)$ is a constant, may I know its expression related to $E_0$?

Answer (score 0):

The intensity is $(E_0)^2/Z_0$, where $Z_0$ is the "impedance of free space" $\approx 377 \Omega$. Multiply by the effective area of your diode to get power. If the diode has a current/power spec, multiply by that, and you're done. Otherwise, divide by the photon energy to get the photon rate, multiply by the quantum efficiency (they'd better give you that) to get the electron current, and multiply by the electron charge to get current.